# Setting a component's state using a function that can be called from everywhere

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, deviceeventemitter

I have a global component called `<MyGlobalComponent/>` that resides in `<App/>`. What I am trying to achieve is that I want to build a global function `showGlobalComponent()` that can be called from any other component, one which sets its visibility and the content rendered inside it (which is another component).

MyGlobalComponent.tsx

```
export type GlobalComponentProps {
  Component: React.FC
  isVisible: boolean
};

export function showGlobalComponent ({Component, isVisible}: GlobalComponentProps) {
  // ??? What do I do here ??? 
  // Supposedly I'd set isVisible & ComponentToRender state variables here, but I can't, I'm outside the function
}
    
function MyGlobalComponent() {
  const [ComponentToRender, setComponentToRender] = useState<React.FC | null>(null);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState<boolean>(false)

  return (
    <View style={APPSTYLE.myComponentStyle} />
      {
        isVisible &&
        <>
         ComponentToRender
        </>
      } 
    </View>
  )
```

Here is the example of how I'd call it

AnotherComponent.tsx

```
function AnotherComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    showGlobalComponent({
      isGlobalComponentVisible: true,
      Component => <TertiaryComponent myProp="asds"/>
    })
  }, [])

}
```

I thought about using Redux and only memorizing a string associated with the component I want to render inside `<MyGlobalComponent/> (because you cannot memoize non-serializable stuff with Redux). However, if I want to pass a prop to it like I did above to` TertiaryComponent`, that becomes quite impossible.

A solution I thought of (which I'm in doubt about) is using `DeviceEventEmitter` from `react-native` to emit an event and then listening to it inside an `useEffect` in `<MyGlobalComponent/>`

MyGlobalComponent.tsx

```
export function showGlobalComponent (
  { Component, isVisible }: GlobalComponentProps
) {
  DeviceEventEmitter.emit("myEventName", Component, isVisible);
}

// ...
useEffect(() => {
  const myEvent = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
    "myEventName",
    ({ Component, isVisible }: GlobalComponentProps) => {
      setIsVisible(isVisible)
      setComponentToRender(Component) 
    }
  );
  return () => {
    myEvent.remove();
  };
}, []);
```

However, the behaviour of this is inconsistent and this doesn't seem the right way to do it. Besides, `DeviceEventEmitter` is very poorly documented.
What's a more common or practical way to achieve this?

Comment: So I'd try a React portal and maybe a redux state flag to toggle the visibility. The answers posted here are all surprisingly complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not React-ing very correctly. Instead of declaring some unrestricted global and mutating it locally you should create a React Context provider to hold the state and provide the component and visibility value down to consumers.

Example:

MyGlobalComponentProvider.tsx

```
import {
  PropsWithChildren,
  ReactNode,
  Dispatch,
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useState
} from "react";

type GlobalComponentProps = {
  component: ReactNode;
  setComponent: Dispatch<ReactNode>;
  isVisible: boolean;
  setIsVisible: Dispatch<boolean>;
};

export const MyGlobalComponentContext = createContext<GlobalComponentProps>({
  component: null,
  setComponent: () => null,
  isVisible: false,
  setIsVisible: () => false
});

export const useMyGlobalComponentContext = () =>
  useContext(MyGlobalComponentContext);

export const MyGlobalComponent = () => {
  const { component, isVisible } = useMyGlobalComponentContext();

  return <div>{isVisible ? component : null}</div>;
};

const MyGlobalComponentProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState<ReactNode>(null);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <MyGlobalComponentContext.Provider
      value={{
        component,
        isVisible,
        setComponent,
        setIsVisible
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MyGlobalComponentContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default MyGlobalComponentProvider;
```

Import the `MyGlobalComponentProvider` component and wrap the app or root-level component to provide the context value to *that* sub-ReactTree. Consumers use the exported `useMyGlobalComponentContext` hook to access the values and handle/render accordingly.

App

```
import MyGlobalComponentProvider, {
  MyGlobalComponent,
} from "./MyGlobalComponentProvider";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MyGlobalComponentProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <MyGlobalComponent />
        <AnotherComponent />
      </div>
    </MyGlobalComponentProvider>
  );
}
```

AnotherComponent.tsx

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  useMyGlobalComponentContext
} from "./MyGlobalComponentProvider";

const AnotherComponent = () => {
  const { setComponent, setIsVisible } = useMyGlobalComponentContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    setComponent(<TertiaryComponent myProp="asds" />);
    setIsVisible(true);
  }, []);

  return <h1>AnotherComponent</h1>;
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. Can this somehow be achieved using Redux? For example, if we have multiple such global components, I guess we'd have to wrap everything with more components such as <MyGlobalComponentProvider> inside <App/> and I suppose that wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: @AndrewHoover898 I *could* be achieved using Redux alone, but Redux would beed to be configured to skip the serializability check (*via the serializability middleware*) on the state that is storing the React components (*which is possibly the issue you ran into*). Regarding context provider, you'd only need 1 provider unless you have plans to display more than 1 `MyGlobalComponent` at-a-time, but even then, the single provider could be refactored to allow multiple components and toggling them by id or similar.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it. From what I've researched, disabling the serializable check, even for a specific slice (as per Redux-Toolkit architecture) is a bad idea and could create a lot of unforseen consequences.
I'm already using Redux in my project and I didn't want to mix both approaches, but it seems unavoidable.

Comment: @AndrewHoover898 You can *technically* store whatever you want in Redux, but yes, the general recommendation is to store primitives and JSON serializable objects. You can configure the serializability check to ignore specific actions and state though for the times you do need to store "unconventional" objects like React functions in state. You could alternatively store the *name* of the component and the props you want to pass it in the store, and then use a lookup map on the other side to get the correct React component and pass the stored props to it when rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to React.forwardRef to your global component first. Then you can assign show/hide functions using React.useImperativeHandle hook.

https://github.com/calintamas/react-native-toast-message/blob/main/src/Toast.tsx

Check this implementation, it might help you solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can use references and reference manipulation hooks such as useImperativeHandle for this job.

I prepared an example because I thought it might guide you. An additional way to communicate between components is to use global references.

These methods are generally used in my own projects, such as Modal, Toast, etc., which will be used throughout the application. I use it for elements. Here is the example;

```
import React, {useImperativeHandle, useState} from 'react';
import {Button, View} from 'react-native';

const GlobalComponentRef = React.createRef<GlobalComponentRef>();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <GlobalComponent ref={GlobalComponentRef} />
      <AnotherComponent />
    </View>
  );
};

type GlobalComponentProps = {Component?: React.FC; visible?: boolean};
type GlobalComponentRef = {
  state: () => GlobalComponentProps;
  setComponent: (component: React.FC) => void;
  setVisible: (bool: boolean) => void;
};

const GlobalComponent = React.forwardRef<
  GlobalComponentRef,
  GlobalComponentProps
>(
  (
    {Component = React.Fragment, visible = false}: GlobalComponentProps,
    ref,
  ) => {
    const [_Component, setComponent] = useState<React.FC>(Component);
    const [_visible, setVisible] = useState<boolean>(visible);

    useImperativeHandle(
      ref,
      () => {
        return {
          state: () => ({visible: _visible, Component: _Component}),
          setComponent: (component: React.FC) => setComponent(component),
          setVisible: (bool: boolean) => setVisible(bool),
        };
      },
      [_Component, _visible],
    );

    return <View>{visible && <>ComponentToRender</>}</View>;
  },
);

const AnotherComponent = () => {
  const onPress = () => {
    const {visible} = GlobalComponentRef.current?.state() || {};
    GlobalComponentRef.current?.setVisible(!visible);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title={'Click Me'} onPress={onPress} />
    </View>
  );
};
```